# how to draw lines with arrowheads at end

Tags: flex3

how to draw lines with arrowheads at end

i want to draw connector/line between two shapes with arrow head at end

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Chris Huyler' blog](http://www.huyler.net/flexblog/2009/02/18/drawing-curved-lines-and-arrows-in-flex/) has a post about drawing lines and arrows with Flex, using the [GraphicsUtil](http://www.dncompute.com/blog/2008/07/17/graphicsutil-a-utility-class-for-drawing-arrows.html) library by Noel of DoesNotCompute.